# How do I know which version of node.js I am currently running?

Tags: node.js

I remember I have upgraded to node.js v8.0.0.

And when I type `node --version` I see version number is v8.0.0.

However when I use `which node` on my OS X I see the path is `/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.7.1/bin/node`. Why would that happen? Am I using v8.0.0?

Comment: How did you install node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install node?

Seems like you have used brew to install node in the past, but then upgraded in some other way.

In any case, you should trust the node --version, since this is node itself reporting.

If still in doubt, I would remove and reinstall.

Comment: I can't remember, I have tried many ways to install it because sometimes one doesn't work so I switch to another. The reason I ask this is that I get a warning `Error running install script for optional dependency: "...fsevents" Command failed` message when I use `yarn` to add some module. In the warning I see different node version numbers here and there.

Comment: I would remove node completely and reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have installed one version with Homebrew and one by normal installer?

Depending on your setup you can either remove the 7x version from Homebrew, or update and link to the correct version in Homebrew.

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#can-i-install-my-own-stuff-to-usrlocal

Comment: Thanks just removed everything.